# How to get the url trail followed by spider for each item extracted?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

i am currently working on a spider that crawls on an e-commerce website and extract data. Meanwhile, i need to save the url trail as well in the product such as

```
{
'product_name: "apple iphone 12",
'trail': ["https://www.apple.com/", "https://www.apple.com/iphone/", "https://www.apple.com/iphone-12/"
}
```

Same as the user will go from start page to the product.

I am using `scrapy 2.4.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed previous url as keyword arguments in the callback

source: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments

```
def parse(self, response):
    request = scrapy.Request('http://www.example.com/index.html',
                             callback=self.parse_page2,
                             cb_kwargs=dict(main_url=response.url))
    request.cb_kwargs['foo'] = 'bar'  # add more arguments for the callback
    yield request

def parse_page2(self, response, main_url, foo):
    yield dict(
        main_url=main_url,
        other_url=response.url,
        foo=foo,
    )
```